# Compiling Java program with VBScripts? (NetBeans)

Tags: java, netbeans, vbscript, jar

I have a Java program created that runs VBSscripts after button clicks.

examplescript.vbs

How do I compile these vbs files and then call them to run in the program code? I've been troubleshooting for several days and can't find an answer. Once again I need to be able to run these scripts, at one point I had an input stream created to it but couldn't get it as a vbs file. Hopefully I'm overlooking something here

Edit:
This is what I currently have. With this code I receive the error "Windows Script Host. There is no script extension for file extension ".BufferedInputStream@4e34904""

```
ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    InputStream is = classloader.getResourceAsStream("hello.vbs");
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wscript " + is);
    }
    catch( IOException e ) {
    System.out.println(e);
    System.exit(0);
    }
    System.out.print(is);
```

Comment: vbs is a script and doesn't get compiled possibly you could pass to WScript.exe or CScript.exe what is the most recent code you have tried?

Comment: Your question makes me sad, but before we can possibly answer - **why**? This smells like the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/243725), exactly where do you need to run the vbscripts?

Comment: Currently I have tried many variations of getResourceAsStream. But when passing to the getRuntime().exec(wscript inputstreamvariable) I received an error it wasn't a vbs file

Answer (score 0):

You can run your VBScript as below.

```
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "wscript path/to/examplescript.vbs" );
```

Comment: Yes that works until I try to reference it after a build

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, VBScript is a script and doesn't need compiling. If you want to run code written in VBScript then you can do it this way:

This example uses VBScript to get the Motherboard Serial Number of a computer that is running Microsoft Windows:

```
try {
    // Create a temporary script file named MBSerialxxxxxxxx.vbs
    File file = File.createTempFile("MBSerial",".vbs");
     // Delete the temporary file when virtual machines terminates
    file.deleteOnExit();  
    try (FileWriter fw = new java.io.FileWriter(file)) {
        String vbs = "Set objWMIService = GetObject(\"winmgmts:\\\\.\\root\\cimv2\")\n"
                + "Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _ \n"
                + "   (\"Select * from Win32_BaseBoard\") \n"
                + "For Each objItem in colItems \n"
                + "    Wscript.Echo objItem.SerialNumber \n"
                + "    exit for  ' do the first cpu only! \n"
                + "Next \n";
        fw.write(vbs);
    }

    // Run the VBScript file....
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cscript //NoLogo " + file.getPath());

    // Read in any output to the command window.
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
        // display the output...
        System.out.println(line.trim());
    }
    input.close();
}
catch(IOException e){ 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

Comment: So there is no way to take an existing .vbs file, have it included with the program, and then reference its path?

Comment: @Phasezaa, Are you trying to 'Import' VBScript program into java? Just like importing & using other JAVA classes?

Comment: Yes that is what I am trying to do. And have it begin execution upon a button click inside my java program with getRuntime().exec()

Comment: My question was different.

Comment: Absolutely...you can embed those VBSCript files within your project or simply reference them from any folder you decide to package with your application. The actual important part of the code above you really need is the: `Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cscript //NoLogo " + file.getPath());`. This is what runs the VBScript file because it runs a utility named **cscript** which ultimately runs your VBScript file. You could very well have `Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cscript //NoLogo " + "resources/myscript.vbs");`.

Comment: To further this conversation you should read: [This](https://capturevision.wordpress.com/2008/06/28/how-to-embed-resource-files-using-netbeans/) and [This](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/).